# Android GridView. Avoid bounce/bumps while scrolling

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter, bounce

I have a GridView in my project using the StaggeredGridView (https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid).
Every item is composed by a ImageView and a TextView and the height of the differents ImageViews change from one to the other.

The problem comes when scrolling back to the top, because of the view recycling, when the images re-loads, because of having different heights, the StaggeredGridView 'bounces' a bit and its quite annoying.

I'm trying to remove the bouncing, just like Pinterest's or Etsy's app does (those don't bounce at all and seem to keep the aspect ratio in memory). I've but i didnt manage to figure out how.

Here is some code:

GridItemAdaptem

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder holder;

        if( convertView!=null ){
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout._grid_guide_item, parent, false );
            holder = new Holder( convertView );
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        final Guide guide = this.guides.get(position);
        holder.pic.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int height = Integer.parseInt( guide.getCover().getHeight() ) * holder.pic.getWidth() / Integer.parseInt(guide.getCover().getWidth());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( holder.pic.getWidth(), height );
                    holder.pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    holder.pic.setLayoutParams(params);
                    ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware( holder.pic, true);
                    imageLoader.displayImage(
                        FavoAPI.getImageURL( guide.getCoverId() ),
                        imageAware
                    );
                } catch (NotCoverException ignored) {}
            }
        } );
        holder.name.setText( guide.getName() );
        holder.user.setText( Finals.AUTHOR + guide.getOwner().getFull_name() );

        return convertView;
    }

    static class Holder {
        @InjectView( R.id._grid_item_user )
        TextView user;
        @InjectView( R.id._grid_item_name )
        TextView name;
        @InjectView( R.id._grid_item_pic)
        RoundedCornerImageView pic;

        public Holder( View view ){
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }
```

grid_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/GuidePreviewGuideCardItem"
>
    <nl.favoThings.favoroute.Views.Widgets.RoundedCornerImageView
        android:id="@+id/_grid_item_pic"
        style="@style/gridItem_image"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/formDefault_tinnyMargin"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_grid_item_name"
            style="@style/gridItem_bigText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_grid_item_user"
            style="@style/gridItem_smallText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The style for the ImageView

```
<style name="gridItem_image">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/gridItem_image_margin</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/gridItem_image_margin</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">fitStart</item>
        <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/default_route</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `Runnable`. Just have that code execute straight in the `getView()` call.

As your code stands you are executing that `Runnable` on the UI thread. Meaning you don't gain any benefit to using it in the `getView()` method...which also executes on the UI thread.  You see the resizing because the `View` returned from `getView()` is rendering to the screen before your `Runnable` gets to execute. When it does, it updates the `View` and you see the visual change.  By getting rid of the `Runnable`, your `View` will be at the correct size before it gets rendered to the screen.

Comment: The thread is used to be able to display the default image with the height of the final image while its loading.

I've removed the thread and the problem is still there. In deed, it was even before implementing the thread.

Comment: Hmmm...are you positive the final image size matches what you calculate before hand? I'd output what the View sizes are before and after the final image loads. I'm guessing you'll see that the sizes differ, which explains the visual change in size.

Comment: Ummmm, i did several test while implementing this whole code, because it was driving me crazy (the whole thing in general)
Anyway, i'll try that.
Thank you very much for your time and answers ;)